# Passing image url to create a new contact activity android

Tags: android, android-contacts

Hi i am trying to invoke the create contact form with pre populated data and able to put in the basic details. I am able to put the name,email,phone number but i am not able to load the thumbnail image for the contact. The relevant portion of code is :

```
// Creates a new intent for sending to the device's contacts application
        Intent insertIntent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);

        // Sets the MIME type to the one expected by the insertion activity
        insertIntent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

        /**
         * Added this extra for 4.0 device as on save the onActivityResult was
         * not getting invoked rather a new activity was invoked
         **/
        String INTENT_KEY_FINISH_ACTIVITY_ON_SAVE_COMPLETED = "finishActivityOnSaveCompleted";
        insertIntent.putExtra(INTENT_KEY_FINISH_ACTIVITY_ON_SAVE_COMPLETED,
                true);
        // Sets the new contact name
        insertIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME,
                "name");

        insertIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,
                (Utility.formatPhoneNumber(mCellNumber)));
        insertIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE,
                Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
        insertIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE,
                (Utility.formatPhoneNumber(mOfficeNumber)));
        insertIntent.putExtra(
                ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE_TYPE,
                Phone.TYPE_WORK);

        **insertIntent.putExtra(
                ContactsContract.Intents.ATTACH_IMAGE,getPhotoUrl());**

        // Send out the intent to start the device's contacts app in its add
        // contact activity.
        startActivityForResult(insertIntent,
                REQUEST_CODE_ADD_NEW_CONTACT);
```

Any Pointers on how this can be done . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think using Insert intent it is critical to achieve.

You are using

```
ContactsContract.Intents.ATTACH_IMAGE
```

Which explained this,

```
Starts an Activity that lets the user pick a contact to attach an image to. After picking the contact it launches the image cropper in face detection mode.

Constant Value: "com.android.contacts.action.ATTACH_IMAGE"
```

Here is a complete example explained for what you are looking for.

[Programatically adding contacts with photo using Contacts Provider](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/programatically-adding-contacts-with-photo-using-contacts-provider-in-android-example/)

Comment: @thanks pratik for pointing this and the url..i already went though the link you provided..looks like its directly adding the contact to the DB but what i am looking for is i go to the AddContactActivity with the thumbnail images prepoulated.

Comment: it would be great if you can point me to something which takes me to AddContactActivity with the thumbnail prepoulated.

Comment: I will look into this again and let you know.

Comment: please let me know if found something on this.